# How to manage many html forms and one script?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an html page built with bootstrap 3. On this page I have several forms. The main form processes the entire contents of the page, while all other forms present are used to enter a data in a mysql db without reloading the page.
I don't have any knowledge of ajax and jquery, so i found this script ready to handle the forms without having to reload the page.
The problem is that the script runs only with a form **$("# myform")** while I need many.

The question is, how do I manage various forms within this single script?
Ps. to manage embedded forms I used the function html5 "form".

I hope I was clear

Thank you

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-  1.7.1.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please let us know who you are.",
            email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <form id="frmAddProduct" action="processProduct.php?action=addProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmAddProduct"></form> 
 <form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="post"></form>
```

the submit button for serverals forms:

```
  <input type="text" name="form1" id="form1" value="" placeholder="" form="myform">  
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" form="myform">
```

main form for the page

```
 <button class="btn btn-info" id="btnAddProduct" type="button" onClick="checkAddProductForm();" form="frmAddProduct">
        <i class="ace-icon fa fa-check bigger-110"></i>
            Add
            </button>
```

Comment: `$('form)` will do it for all forms `$('.yourclass')` will do it with a class you specify on all the forms

Comment: Hi, i didn't understand. Which class? css class? could you make a little example? thanks

Comment: $('form').validate({ .. });  will apply validation on all forms in html page without the need of specifying class or id on form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forms that you want to get the script to work on would get a css class:

```
<form id="frmAddProduct" class='formValidation' action="processProduct.php?action=addProduct" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmAddProduct"></form> 
<form id="myform" class='formValidation' name="myform" action="" method="post"></form>
```

and then you would modifiy to script to call validate like this

```
$(".formValidation").validate({
      // your code here
});
```

Now any form with the css class 'formValidation' will now have that script act upon it to handle the submit change it to:

```
$('.formValidation').on('submit', function () {
    $.post('process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    });
})
```

Comment: What changes? if i have, for example 3 forms i can't have for all the same class or id. How the script can recognize from which form is processing the data? Every form has to insert differents data into differents mysql tables.

Comment: change your submit handler to be explicit too see my edits